# angular 10 adsense is not showing - ng2-adsense

Tags: angular, ads, adsense, angular10, google-ads-api

I'm using angular 10 and adsense to show ads in my website, I used ng2-adsense but the ads not working, any advice?

The ads not working on localhost or at firebase deploy: https://gifcreator-be34b.web.app/

Comment: Did you solve this problem?